# Can't get LIKE to work with wp_query

Tags: wp-query

Using a theme that uses Job Manager, the listings are by city, I want someone who searches for 'ondon' to get all listings in 'London'. Tried every variation of the following and nothing is working:

```
$myArgs = array(
        'orderby'          => '_post_date',
        'order'            => 'ASC',        
        'post_type'        => 'job_listing',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                          'key' => 'job_listing_region',
                          'value' => "'" . $city . "'",
                          'compare' => 'LIKE'
                          )
                    )
    );
    $cityschools = new WP_Query( $myArgs );
```

'job_listing_region' is a checkbox in the CMS. Any guidance would be apprecieated.

Comment: this is off-topic, but the region is a taxonomy, not a meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up the meta_query value like:

```
'value' => "'" . $city . "'",
```

it gets translated to `LIKE '%\'ondon\'%'` in the final SQL query, which matches things like `L'ondon'` or `L'ondon'er`  but not `London`.

But you actually want it to be like: `LIKE '%ondon%'` - so you should do:

```
'value' => $city,
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I haven't noticed that this actually is Job Manager plugin related and the `job_listing_region` is a taxonomy. In that case you should try to do something like:

```
// get taxonomy id's with names matching the query string $city
$foo_terms = get_terms( 'job_listing_region', array('name__like' => $city) );
$term_ids = [];
if ($foo_terms) {
    foreach ($foo_terms as $foo_term) {
        $term_ids[] = $foo_term->term_id;
    }
}

// get jobs_listing entries matching retrieved id's
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'job_listing',
            'post_status'      => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                 array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_region',
                     'field'    => 'term_id',
                     'terms' => $term_ids,
                     'operator' => 'IN'
                 )
            )
);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it's not even finding 'london'.

Comment: I have updated my answer assuming that `job_listing_region` is a taxonomy of the `job_listing` post type.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer. Seems like there should be a more straightforward way to do it but it works.

Comment: BTW: for future ref, are all the other job manager fields custom fields?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can find it in the documentation, but you can search the source files for custom posts and custom taxonomies definitions.